# How to change color settings in DrJava ? (error)

Tags: permissions, java, colors

When I click "Apply" in settings of DrJava, it says:

> Could not save changes to your ".drjava" file in your home directory.
>   java.io.IOException: Permission denied

Permissions are:

```
drwxr-xr-x 30 pypaut pypaut 4096 avril 14 12:24 /home/pypaut 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1259 janv. 1 2017 /home/pypaut/.drjava
```

Comment: What is the output of `ls -ld $HOME $HOME/.drjava`

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x 30 pypaut pypaut 4096 avril 14 12:24 /home/pypaut `
`-rw-r--r--  1 root   root   1259 janv.  1  2017 /home/pypaut/.drjava `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something created the .drjava directory with root ownership (or later chown'd it that way). You'll need to reset that to be your user:

```
sudo chown pypaut:pypaut ~/.drjava
```

If you do not have root-level authority to do this, you could rename the directory:

```
mv ~/.drjava ~/.aside-drjava
mkdir ~/.drjava
```